# How To Install Rofi 1.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I have tried to install rofi on 16.04 but ran into issues with this package `libxkbcommon`

As stated [here on the package's github](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi/blob/next/INSTALL.md#debian-or-ubuntu) the version of rofi that is availible on apt-get is very old. I want to try to install the latest (1.5) version but every time [I follow the instructions](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi/blob/master/INSTALL.md#install-a-checkout-from-git) on building it on my own I run an issue where my `libxkbcommon` package isn't updated enough. It calls for v0.7 but I only have 0.5.

I have not found a way to upgarde `libxkbcommon` to 0.7 so I may install Rofi. Is there an easier way to do this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I successfully installed rofi v.1.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 by adding this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~jasonpleau/+archive/ubuntu/rofi) maintained by Jason Pleau.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jasonpleau/rofi
sudo apt update
```

And then install rofi or upgrade your system if rofi is already installed.

```
sudo apt install rofi
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the linked readme for that package on github,

> This will cause issues with newer scripts (i.e. with clerk) and misses important updates and bug-fixes. Newer versions of Rofi however requires versions of xcb-util-xrm and libxkbcommon that are not available in the 16.04 repositories. These need to be manually installed before rofi can be installed either via source code or Zesty version from the ubuntu's launchpad page for rofi.

It's not particularly recommended that you install those alternative dependencies from their repo (as it could potentially lead to breakage) but if you want the new version of Rofi you can add their repo and install the versioned dependencies from there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "you can add their repo and install the versioned dependencies from there." Could you please describe how I would install their versioned dependencies from the repo?

Comment: Do you by any chance have the backports source enabled?

Comment: No I don't, but I'm open to trying if that makes things easier.

Comment: It's been a little while since I really played around with Ubuntu, but you should be able to enable that from within the software sources app. If the package isn't available there, I'd kind of recommend moving to ubuntu 17.10 or 18.04 when it comes out instead of attempting to manually install it on 16.04. LTS releases tend to have somewhat out of date software versions that just have bug fixes applied to keep the system more stable. Trying to install newer libraries and dependencies is likely to make the system unstable and result in package breakage down the line.